# Which 3D software (MAC) can export basic or modified primitive wireframe objects as a vector? Example included

Tags: print-design, vector, 3d, stroke

I would like to create some large prints so the scalable vector with editable stroke weight is necessary. Found these examples that would be perfect for my needs.

Any tips would be much appreciated

[image]

Comment: Well for example blender and maya.

Comment: Have you looked at/researched anything? I understand the thought that asking here may yield some results, but this isn't Google.

Comment: Hi, I did some research. Actually I tried Cinema 4D with sketch and toon material but even if I tried to tweak it the result is mostly unusable. I never touched Blender or any other 3D modeling software so would appreciate any experience with similar scenario. I really don't want to learn any difficult software as from what you can see these are just basic primitives and imho should be exported easily.

Comment: Does raw PostScript count? A reasonable amount of 3D programming goes a long way.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at Blender using a couple of exporting add-ons:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/freestyle/export_svg.html

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6675/can-blender-export-2d-curves-to-svg

> I really don't want to learn any difficult software as from what you can see these are just basic primitives and imho should be exported easily

You need to learn some parts of the software or ask someone else to do it for you.

Is the program complex and can be challenging? Yes, but if you need to make a short film. But it is pretty simple when you have specific steps to follow, so follow some specific steps:

1. Install the program, add a primitive, and configure the parameters.
2. Install the add-ons
3. Export